# What is the word "madness" doing in the first chapter's title of Automata Theory, Languages and Computation by Hopcroft, Motwani, Ullman?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

The chapter's title is "[Automata: The Methods and the Madness](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321455363)".  This title came along in the second edition and remains in the third edition.  In the first edition, the the second chapter's title is "Finite Automata and Regular Expressions".

The word "madness" doesn't show up anywhere else in the third edition.  Why is the chapter named like that?  I haven't read every word of chapter one, but it doesn't look like there's any explanation in it.

Comment: The chapter title is probably derived from Shakespeare - in *Hamlet* Polonius says "Though this be madness, yet there is method in 't".

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really a question about computer science, or a question that can be reasonably answered at all. To me, it seems that you might as well ask why the cover of the book has a certain colour. Perhaps it is on topic if you would ask specifically whether there is some CS concept that is related to this name, to which I would expect the answer to be 'no'.

Comment: @gandalf61 What about converting your remark as an answer to the question?

Comment: I'd mark as accepted it.